# Where I can find files with language on android custom rom

Tags: settings, custom-roms

I have custom rom MIUI 4.7.23 default language is Chinese. I can't set to other language because I am on first setup. I don't know Chinese and can't skip this welcome screen. I want to change or add Polish language but this is not possible it can be English version I can't find this as global version of this rom.

The structure of .zip file is META-INF/, system/, boot.img, logo.bin

I suppose there is .xml file if it is?

The first I know this is welcome MIUI I click on the one button something like next by intuition

The 2nd is WLAN I switch it off click something like next in Chinese

Comment: which is your device? MIUI 4.7.23 means your trying to install MIUi 4 which is very old. I also wanted to know that, if you are trying to install a ported ROM on a non-xiaomi device.

Comment: yes this is non-xiaomi device Goclever quantum 350 with jelly bean 4.2.2 and MIUI version 4 because it works on under jelly bean base want to update to  MIUI v5

Comment: There's no such thing like a huge file with all of your ROM translated, OP. Any single APK package can have a number of **strings.xml** files inside its **res** directory, which define that app's available languages.

Answer (score 0):

## Own answer but no solution related to this question

Think too fast asked question

**Ok I found it!!!**

but this not the answer on this question because this isn't related to file with language but is very helpful I also changed language to English in settings by luck `:)`

I did this:

(I type in English because I changed the language on it)
Just remove SIM card and by intuition press next and turn off 2 switches and had something Chinese text with `!`

1. Clicked `Settings` blue gear icon
2. the tab on the right (this is `general settings`) there are 2 tabs
3. icon with keyboard is the language! press it
4. next press the first button and change to English for example `:)`

But I can't take screenshots of phone `:|`